# Unable to click continue while Reinstall/Disk utilities in Boot

Tags: macos, high-sierra, disk-utility, startup, install

[image]

I am try to upgrade Sierra to high Sierra, unable to click continue Upgrade/Reinstall,Disk Utility, Restore from machine backup, And Get help online in MacBook Pro booting time.
Kindly help me..

Comment: Using your trackpad, I assume? Try a wired mouse, and if that doesn't work try another USB port with the mouse.

Comment: Yes, I'm using trackpad, I will try wired mouse and let you know, thanks for reply

Comment: Yes working now, Steve Chambers your rockstar, you saved my days.

Comment: I've provided my comment as an answer, if you could do me the favor of accepting it as the answer. And glad to hear that worked!

Answer (score 1):

For a MacBook Pro there is a possibility. Assuming you are using the trackpad to click, it may be worth trying a wired USB mouse. Try on all USB ports just in case.

Oddly enough older MacBooks have actual ADB bus pointing devices, long after Apple supported ADB as an available port. Not sure if this is one of those Macs but a curious historical note, none the less.